# Custom fancybox - can't click link in title

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I've created a custom Fancybox implementation that displays the title on the left-hand side of the image. The problem is that inside any galleries, links inside the title of the image can't be clicked because the `fancybox-left` link sits above it and blocks the click. You can click the first link in the gallery because the left button does not appear.

I've tried changing z-indexes and all that, but am currently stuck. Any help would be great.

You can find the implementation [here](http://sarahewain.com/paintings.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this css

```
.fancybox-left {
  left:7.5em;
}
```

this will move left link to the right (it will display on the image)

Comment: Perfect. Should have thought of that in the first place :)